# Transparent color of Bootstrap-3 Navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having problem with setting bootstrap3 navbar transparency or opacity color. I didin't change anything in bootstrap.css or bootstrap-theme.css 
In my menu I'm Trying to put image under that and set color to black-transparent or black with opacity like here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjk4W.png
You can see that opacity ammount is not very high but it is , and i have to do something like that. When I'm changing anything the color is setting white so please help me.

The Code below:

```
<div class="navbar transparent navbar-inverse navbar-static-top hr">
    <div class="navbar-brand logo"></div>
    <div class="navbar-brand-right">
    </div>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav mineul" style="font-size:17px;margin-top:9px; color:white;">
              <li><a href="#">Test1</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Test1</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Test1</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And bootply:
http://bootply.com/106966

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```css
.navbar {
   background-color: transparent;
   background: transparent;
   border-color: transparent;
}

.navbar li { color: #000 }
```

http://bootply.com/106969

Comment: Thank you , now it's transparent. 
Can you tell me how put image under navbar ? Answer: Posision Relative with top -px

Comment: Working for navbar class but my "Toggle navigation" (navbar-toggle, navbar-nav) become transparent too.

Comment: Played a little bit more on this fiddle. Got this: https://www.codeply.com/p/2GzQLtGRL5

Answer (score 3):

you can use this for your css , mainly use css3 rgba as your background in order to control the opacity  and use a background fallback for older browser , either using a solid color or a transparent .png image.

```
.navbar {
   background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);   /* for latest browsers */
   background: #000;  /* fallback for older browsers */
}
```

More info:
http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/

Answer (score 3):

The class is .navbar-default. You need to create a class on your custom css .navbar-default.And follow the css code. Also if you don’t want box-shadow on your menu, you can put on the same class.

```
 .navbar-default {
      background-color:transparent !important;
      border-color:transparent;
      background-image:none;
      box-shadow:none;  
 }
```

[image]

To change font navbar color, the class is to change – .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a see the code bellow:

```
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
     font-size:20px; 
     color:#fff; 
 }
```

ref : http://twitterbootstrap.org/bootstrap-navbar-background-color-transparent/

Comment: still have box border, and link color didnt change?

Answer (score -2):

1. Go to http://px64.net/
2. mess around with opacity, add your image or choose color.
3. copy either html or css(css is easier) the site spits out.
4. Select your element aka the navbar.
5. .navbar{
   background-image:url(link that the site provides);
   background-repeat:repeat;
6. Enjoy.