# How to make Twitter Bootstrap Navbar transparent?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make my bootstrap `navbar` transparent. I am using bootstrap `navbar-inverse` and trying to add opacity by `rgba()`. I want my navbar to be transparent as shown in the image below:

[image]

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: FuturaBook;
  src: url('fonts/FuturaStd-Light_1.otf');
}
body{
  font-family: 'FuturaBook', Arial, sans-serif;
}

/***************************************************************************
Navigation Bar
****************************************************************************/

.navbar-inverse{
  background-color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.5);
  border-bottom: none;

}

.navbar-header{
  width:100%;
  height: 90px;

}
.navbar-header #brand{
  font-family: 'FuturaBook', Arial, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20pt;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;

}

.mynav li 
{
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  padding-top: 36px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  /* margin-top: 16px; */
  height: 90px;
}
.mynav li:last-child{
  border-right: 1px solid white;
} 

.mynav li a{
  color:white;
}
.mynav li a:hover{
  text-decoration: none;
}
/* .mynav li a:active{
background-color: black;
}*/
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-transparent navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" id="brand">Fashion Garage</a>

        <div class="mynav pull-right">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="">TRENDS</a></li>
            <li><a href="">PRODUCTS</a></li>
            <li><a href="">DESIGNERS</a></li>
            <li><a href="">MEMBERS</a></li>
            <li><a href="">SEARCH</a></li>
            <li><a href="">MY ACCOUNT</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /mynav -->
      </div><!-- /navbar-header -->
    </div><!-- /container -->

    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="img/lady-1.jpg" alt="Lady-1">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            ...
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="img/lady-2.jpg" alt="Lady-2">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            ...
          </div>
        </div>
        ...
      </div>

      <!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </nav><!-- /nav -->

</div><!-- /wrapper -->
```

[image: new nav with white background]

Comment: Can you include all of your CSS please? Because with the code you provided, it seems to work fine.  I would guess that the .navbar-inverse style is being overridden by something else in your CSS Here is a codepen of it working: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGYvWx

Comment: Added full css as u asked for @Zac.Ledyard

Comment: Interesting, it still seems to be working for me here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGYvWx

Answer (score 3):

If you're still having problems I suggest just start over and use this : 
It's pretty simple and straight forward. Don't add another class to `navbar` just a suggestion. Also you can replace the **link** of the Bootstrap CSS and JS. It's just the CDN link. Here's the output if your're interested.

[image]

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    body{
        background-image: url('http://seamlesspatternchecker.com/hash/seamless-pattern-samples/a/3/5/a35-vector-vector-seamless-simple-pattern-curtain-design-modern-stylish-texture-repeating-abstract-158117696.jpg');
    }

    .navbar{
        border: none;
        border-radius: 0;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    }
</style>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
          </form>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the  portion of your website, load your new custom CSS file after the default bootstrap stylesheet.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
</head>
```

In your custom.css

```
.navbar {
    background-color: transparent;
    background: transparent;
    border-width: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.navbar {
   background-color: transparent;
   background: transparent;
}

.navbar li { color: #000 }
```

**Update:**
On `CSS` seconde line replace: `<nav class="navbar navbar-transparent navbar-inverse">` to `<nav class="navbar navbar-transparent">`

**Possible answers:**

[Transparent color of Bootstrap-3 Navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21218577/transparent-color-of-bootstrap-3-navbar)

[css to make bootstrap navbar transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16392952/css-to-make-bootstrap-navbar-transparent)

Comment: Check the update: replace `<nav class="navbar navbar-transparent navbar-inverse">` to `<nav class="navbar navbar-transparent">`

Comment: Tried with update.. Getting white navbar now. thank you for ur effort but some thing else is the issue @ptCoder

Comment: Try add this .`navbar-inner { background:transparent; }`

Comment: NO help :(.. Navbar becomes white

Comment: White or transparent?

Comment: Added new navbar .. Its white

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code pen which i have tried making the navigation bar transparent and responsive. Hope it helps you.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top opaque-navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navMain">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" style="color:white;"></span>

  </button>
```

[You can find the rest of the code here](http://codepen.io/hanu73/pen/YZaowO?editors=1100)